# Creating a function with a string variable and array parameters in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, parameters

I am trying to create a function with 2 parameters one is name variable and 2 an array with name list.
If the name os in the array it should return or print 'true' in the browser otherwise it should give 'false'

```
For ex: 
nameexistCheck('Johnny',['Jack','Sarah','Andy','Johnny']) // true
nameexistCheck('Johnny',['Jack','Sarah','Andy'])// false
```

I would be very grateful someone shows me how to write logic to this issue. I am a new developer and I have tried many ways but it not working.

This is one of them.

```
nameexistCheck($name, $names);
$names = array('Johnny', 'Jack')
foreach($names as $value){
  if ($name===$value){
    echo 'true';
  }else{
    echo 'false';
  }
}
nameexistCheck('Johnny', ['Jack', 'Sarah','Johnny']);
```

Output is false false true
It is not working properly I need only one output true or false. And another problem is in my code I have write a name by hand to the list but, it should fill it automaticly. Please help me with this task.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious you have no idea what you're doing so I will not explain further but I will suggest you take some basic PHP tutorials. For now, this should work for you

```
function nameexistCheck($name, $names){
    return in_array($name, $names) ? 'true' : 'false';
}

echo nameexistCheck('Johnny', ['Jack', 'Sarah','Johnny']); // true
```

Comment: Yes, ur right! I have to take some tutorials in this field. But, anyway thank you very much. I appriciate it!

Comment: @JahongirAripov kindly consider marking this as the accepted answer.